# Django rendering a page with a large selection. Could this be faster?

Tags: python, django

All the code in this example is just a simplified representation. The actual code is more complex, but I believe that for this question this should be sufficient. I am unfortionaly stuck with a very old version of Django, which I can not change: 1.7.1

I render a .html page using django. The html page contains instances of `artist`.

```
class Artist(EmptyModelBase):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    etc. etc.
```

When a request comes, it goes to `views.py` where we do this:

```
def some_function(req):
   # do some stuff
   filter = # filter actually comes from the request
   items = Artist.objects.filter(**filter)
   items = items[0:20] # return max 20 instances, even if we have more
   context = {'artists':items}
   return render(req, 'artist.html' , context)
```

The .html itself is relatively simple. It contains more then this, but this is the essence:

```
{% for item in artists  %}
     <p class="artist"> {{ item.name | safe}} </p> 
{% endfor %}
```

Everything above works as expected. Based on the request, and the filter in the request, there will be anywhere between 1 and 250k instances of `Artist` returned by the query. I take a slice of max 20 instances, and then render the page.

My issue: if the request returns very few instances, the page loads very fast (~ 200ms range). However, if the original query returns close to 250k instances, the page loads very slow (~ 4000ms).

I assume that this is because, when Django renders the page, executing the query takes more time with the large query relative to small queries, because the slice is taken AFTER all the results are found.

**Is there a way to speed this up?**

Comment: The slicing is *not* done after querying. `items` is *not* a collection. It is a `QuerySet`, it *represents* a query. If you slice, you construct a new `QuerySet`, and only the latter will be evaluated.

Comment: If you however use a `items = list(Artist.objects.filter(...))`, then of course you force evaluation, and then indeed there is a serious performance bottleneck.

Comment: So does that mean that taking a slice on a large or small `QuerySet` takes the same amount of time? Then I don't understand why the larger query takes more time, if I take a slice.

Comment: @MitchessVanZuylen: it means it will make the query with `... OFFSET ... LIMIT ...`, and normally most databases can boost performance for this, although of course it can still be slower if the filtering is complex.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the limit to the initial ORM query.

```
items = Artist.objects.filter(**filter)[0:20]
```

The current 2 line method is making 2 queries.